# How to count words frequency by removing non-letters of a string?

Tags: c#, string, word-count, distinct-values

I have a string:

```
var text = @"
I have a long string with a load of words,
and it includes new lines and non-letter characters.
I want to remove all of them and split this text to have one word per line, then I can count how many of each word exist."
```

What is the best way to go about removing all non-letter characters, then splitting each word onto a new line so I can store and count how many of each word there are?

```
var words = text.Split(' ');

foreach(var word in words)
{
    word.Trim(',','.','-');
}
```

I have tried various things such as `text.Replace(characters)` with `whitespace` then split. I have tried Regex (which I would rather not use).

I have also tried to use the StringBuilder class to take the characters from the text (string) and only appending the character if it is a letter a-z / A-Z.

Also tried calling sb.Replace or sb.Remove the characters I don't want before storing them in a Dictionary. But I still seem to end up with characters I don't want?

Everything I try, I seem to have at least one character I don't want in there and can't quite figure out why it isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: `Trim()` returns the trimmed string from the method call, it does not mutate the string you call `Trim()` on. You'll need to adjust your code to use the value returned by the calls to `Trim()` and update your array of words with the result.

Comment: Do you have to move them to a new line? You could try using regex to see how many strings are matching with your regexp?

Comment: A simple regex would catch all words *without* generating all the strings splitting would, eg `Regex.Matches(@"\w+")` would capture all consecutive word characters. The match count would be the number of words. [Word characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#WordCharacter) include digits though. `"[a-zA-Z]+"` would capture just English letters, while `"\p{L}+"` would capture letters, no matter the language

Comment: With `non-letter` do you count 1 or 2 words? Do you want to skip numbers too like in `this is a 10 number` will be 4 words?

Comment: non-letter would be two words, ideally, I would replace the hyphen with whitespace, so I could split each word onto a new line. I don't actually have any numbers in my text so it is not important at this stage, but I would probably choose to just skip over them

Comment: *Do* use regex. It's the right tool for this job. `Regex.Matches(text,@"\p{L}+").Count` will return 46, counting `non-letter` as two words. `Regex.Matches(text,@"[-\p{L}]+").Count.Dump();` includes the dash in the matches, returning 45. That could match standalone dashes though, so `@"\p{L}+-?\p{L}*"` will match words with at least one letter and possibly one dash followed by letters

Comment: How would I go about counting how many of each word there are? Rather than grabbing how many words are in the string overall.

So I would store a Dictionary of each word i.e.

"I want to count, count, these words."
I : 1 
want : 1
to: 1
count: 2
these: 1
words: 1

Comment: @user11181954 you can use a groupBy also. I think the Dictionary route is good though

Comment: @user11181954 Answer updated to take the last word (the test worked because of the point at the end).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using an extension method without RegEx nor Linq**

```
static public class StringHelper
{
  static public Dictionary<string, int> CountDistinctWords(this string text)
  {
    string str = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
    var words = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    char charCurrent;
    Action processBuilder = () =>
    {
      var word = builder.ToString();
      if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(word) )
        if ( !words.ContainsKey(word) )
          words.Add(word, 1);
        else
          words[word]++;
    };
    for ( int index = 0; index < str.Length; index++ )
    {
      charCurrent = str[index];
      if ( char.IsLetter(charCurrent) )
        builder.Append(charCurrent);
      else
      if ( !char.IsNumber(charCurrent) )
        charCurrent = ' ';
      if ( char.IsWhiteSpace(charCurrent) )
      {
        processBuilder();
        builder.Clear();
      }
    }
    processBuilder();
    return words;
  }
}
```

It parses all chars rejecting all non letters while creating a dictionary of each words having the number of occurrences counted.

**Test**

```
var result = text.CountDistinctWords();
Console.WriteLine($"Found {result.Count()} distinct words:");
Console.WriteLine();
foreach ( var item in result )
  Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}");
```

**Result on your sample**

```
Found 36 distinct words:

I: 3
have: 2
a: 2
long: 1
string: 1
with: 1
load: 1
of: 3
words: 1
and: 3
it: 1
includes: 1
new: 1
lines: 1
non: 1
letter: 1
characters: 1
want: 1
to: 2
remove: 1
all: 1
them: 1
split: 1
this: 1
text: 1
one: 1
word: 2
per: 1
line: 1
then: 1
can: 1
count: 1
how: 1
many: 1
each: 1
exist: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the solution with dictionary for counting frequencies is a best practice in terms of performance and clarity. Here's my version which is slightly different from the accepted answer (I use *String.Split()* instead of iterating through string's chars):

```
var text = @"
    I have a long string with a load of words,
    and it includes new lines and non-letter characters.
    I want to remove all of them and split this text to have one word per line, then I       can count how many of each word exist.";

var words = text.Split(new [] {',', '.', '-', ' ', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var freqByWord = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (freqByWord.ContainsKey(word))
    {
        freqByWord[word]++; // we found the same word
    }
    else
    {
        freqByWord.Add(word, 1); // we don't have this one yet
    }
}

foreach (var word in freqByWord.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{word}: {freqByWord[word]}");
}
```

And the results are pretty much the same:

```
I: 3
have: 2
a: 2
long: 1
string: 1
with: 1
load: 1
of: 3
words: 1
and: 3
it: 1
includes: 1
new: 1
lines: 1
non: 1
letter: 1
characters: 1
want: 1
to: 2
remove: 1
all: 1
them: 1
split: 1
this: 1
text: 1
one: 1
word: 2
per: 1
line: 1
then: 1
can: 1
count: 1
how: 1
many: 1
each: 1
exist: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Using regex excluding non letter characters. This will also give you a collection of all the words.

```
var text = @"
I have a long string with a load of words,
and it includes new lines and non-letter characters.
I want to remove all of them and split this text to have one word per line, then I can count how many of each word exist.";

var words = Regex.Matches(text, @"[A-Za-z ]+").Cast<Match>().SelectMany(n => n.Value.Trim().Split(' '));
int wordCount = words.Count();
```