# Get array of words from a string

Tags: c#, string

I am working on an requirement where I need to get all the words from a string into an array.
A 'word' is described as any sequence of non-space charachters.
There can be any number of whitespace charachters present in the string.

Input Examples :

```
"  Hello World!!  "
"Hello World!!"
"  Hello       World!!    "
```

In all above cases the output should be ["Hello","World!!"]

Now I have tried to solve the example myself and have below code :

```
public string[] GetWords(string s)
   {
        s=s.Trim();
        while(s.Contains("  "))
        {
            s = s.Replace("  ", " ");
        }

        string[] input=s.Split(' ');
        return input;
   }
```

I am getting correct result using the above code. My concerns is there any way the code can be made clean or more optimized than it currently is.

Comment: The definition of "clean" might be opinion-based. For "optimized", you also need to specify in which way: fast? small memory footprint? small code size?

Comment: `string.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` would be an idea

Comment: @dymanoid I was looking for result in less number of steps than I am performing.

Comment: @Homungus Thanks, your solution did the trick for me

Comment: Also without RegEx, to adapt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734248/how-to-count-words-frequency-by-removing-non-letters-of-a-string/58734800#58734800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code snippet:

```
var str = "  Hello World!!  ";
string[] array = str.Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The result will be ["Hello","World!!"]

Note: `new Char[] { ' ' }` if multiple characters need to be handled. Otherwise, you can use the following

```
string[] array = str.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regular expression:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

public string[] GetWords(string s) =>
    Regex.Matches(s, @"[^\s]+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I would use `Regex.Split()`.